# Django how to save/edit json with SplitJSONWidget

Tags: json, django, django-views

I`m using Django 1.9 with this [library](https://github.com/abbasovalex/django-SplitJSONWidget-form) as following:

models.py:

```
class Policy(models.Model):
    config = JSONField(max_length=50000, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True, default="")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py:

```
class PolicyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ('name',)

    attrs = {'class': 'special', 'size': '25'}
    data = forms.CharField(widget=SplitJSONWidget(attrs=attrs, debug=True))
```

views.py:

```
def policy_new(request):
    json = {
        "all": {
            "active": True
        }
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PolicyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.config = form.data
        post.save()
        return redirect('ui:config-list')
    else:
        form = PolicyForm(initial={'data': json})

    template = 'api/policy_template.html'
    context = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
    return render_to_response(template, context)


def policy_edit(request, pk):
    policy = get_object_or_404(Policy, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PolicyForm(request.POST, instance=policy)
        if form.is_valid():
           post = form.save(commit=False)
           post.config = form.data
           post.save()
           return redirect('ui:config-list')
    else:
        form = PolicyForm(instance=policy, initial={'data': policy.config})
    return render(request, 'api/policy_template.html', {'form': form})
```

I have a problem with saving and editing the json:

**Saving:**

[image]

**Editing first time:**

[image]

**Editing second time:**

[image]

As you can see the json is concatenating with itself and adding the crf token and the name to the json (wtf?). What is wrong with the saving and editing functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the saving process and the solution is :

```
post = form.save(commit=False)
post.config = form.cleaned_data['data']
post.save()
```

In both policy_new() and policy_edit() functions.